# SSRS Deploy multiples folders

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a server with too many folders and every folder has different data sources (for different databases), but their reports are same for each folder:

[image: reportserver]

I would like to know if I can deploy my reports in different folders at the same time for one server from my Visual Studio Report Project? Can I do with some script or Can I clone or duplicate the folders

These are my folders:

Comment: If you create a reporting solution in Visual Studio you can do this.

Comment: yes, I have a VS Report Project

Comment: Please disregard the comment above. I thought you were asking to duplicate your folder structure to different servers, not one report to multiple folders. One thing comes to mind - create a linked report and have one physical .rdl file linked to multiple locations in ssrs. I cant remember how they show up in the reporting solution (a linked item perhaps).

Comment: How did you end up resolving this issue?